# How to add an item to an XML string-array from Java and then save it?

Tags: java, android, xml, save, arrays

I have an XML file that is as follows:

```
<string-array name="Cube_type_entries">
    <item>2x2x2</item>
    <item>3x3x3</item>
    <item>4x4x4</item>
    <item>5x5x5</item>
    <item>6x6x6</item>
    <item>7x7x7</item>
    <item>8x8x8</item>
    <item>9x9x9</item>
    <item>Pyraminx</item>
    <item>Megaminx</item>
    <item>Clock</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="Cube_type_values">
    <item>x2</item>
    <item>x3</item>
    <item>x4</item>
    <item>x5</item>
    <item>x6</item>
    <item>x7</item>
    <item>x8</item>
    <item>x9</item>
    <item>Pyraminx</item>
    <item>Megaminx</item>
    <item>Clock</item>
</string-array>
```

(It has the resource tag, and the other stuff needed)

And, I would like to add an item to Cube_type_entries, so a user could customize what he would like in it. So, the user hits an Enter button, I have the code for that, but I do not know how to insert it into the string-array then save it.
(I am not looking for a dynamic one, I simply want it to be able to save it to the table every now and then)

So, how do I add to an XML string-array and then save it in Java?

Comment: You can't modify the resource xmls AFAIK.

Comment: You can make use of `File Operation`, but I am not sure thats how you wanted.

Comment: _What I need is the Java code to insert and save something_ no, this is not how SO works, here you should ask question, not post your requirements.

Comment: @Swapnil I haven't found anything I could try.

Comment: @Pradeep Simha That is my question. I just put it in a statement. Just to summarize, how I should have put it: How do I insert something to XML string-array then save it? I will change that.

Comment: @DXPower, I think you need to use file operation, like smit is saying

Answer (score 0):

you could load your xml into objects, I think simpleXML is a library you can use with android.